# How to make Media Query work when IE loads?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, media-queries

I have the following media query in a `<style>` block, within the `<head>` of my index.htm file....

```
@media screen and (min-width: 40.5em) {
  header[role="banner"]  {border:solid 1px red;}  
}
```

But IE10 will not produce a red border around my header when the page loads.  Now if I take the style out of that media query, then IE will process the red border when the page reloads.

What is the secret here in getting this displayed in IE10, with my page loads?

Also...I have the following set in my

```
<head>
...
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
...
</head>
```

px does not work for me either...

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 100px) {
  header[role="banner"] {border:solid 1px red;}
}
```

no show...

**UPDATE**

I figured out whats going on.  Within my style block I have the following css code...

```
@media screen and (min-width: 5em) {

   //various css rules for mobile view
}
```

and right below it I have....

```
@media screen and (max-width: 40.5em) {

  //various css rules for desktop view
}
```

Chrome understands this on my desktop browser and reads the second media query.  But IE10 gets stuck on the first one.  My goal is to have a mobile first approach, but not for IE to get stuck there if the screen size is larger.  That is my issue...

When I remove the 1st media query, the 2nd one works in IE.  How can i keep both of them and have IE know to ignore the first for larger screens...?

Comment: Are you sure the screen is wider than 40.5em?

Comment: yes, i have it full screen, on my desktop pc.

Comment: Have you try to use pixel instead of "em"?

Comment: That doesn't mean anything if you have a 640x480 resolution ;) Try px instead, though, as mentioned right above me.

Comment: px doesnt work either...

Comment: Does the style just not show in IE or does the same problem happen in other browsers? It shouldn't be a problem with IE 10 since your page is forcing it to load in IE 9. It quite possibly could be a problem with IE 9 though...

Comment: In your px answer, you are using `max-device-width`. Your desktop's `max-width` is bigger than that. How about `@media screen and (min-width: 100px)`?

Comment: I just updated my original post. Looking for any good feedback to the issue.  Thanks so much!

Comment: What you can do is set up your css so mobile styles are first and not enclosed in any `@media` queries. Then, as screen size increases to whatever values you determine, set up `@media` queries.

Comment: when viewing in IE.. if you use the developer inspector what does the document mode show.. is it in Browser Mode: IE10 (Document Mode: Standards) ?

Comment: Are we talking about mobile or desktop?  The viewport meta tag won't help with IE at all since it honors the `@viewport` rule instead (see: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/)

Comment: @PAPAFRESH, yes its in IE10 standards mode

Comment: @disinfor your solution worked.  If you write it out as an answer, I'll give you a green check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your mobile styles first without calls to any `@media` queries (those will be your defaults). From there, you can use `@media` queries to adjust for larger/different screen resolutions.